# How to fetch Speech Result text from twilio call logs using python

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I am trying to fetch call logs from twilio which was successful from twilio docs, but I also want to fetch the conversation text which is present in twilio request parameters

[image]

please guide me on this as my requirement is not available in twilio docs.

Comment: Have you tried to parse the request parameter `SpeechResult`? Can you share the code you used and what didn't work as expected?